# Unity ResolveAll Generics Interface

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm using Unity IoC, I'd like to register mapping of non generic class to generic interface. After that I'd like to use ResolveAll method for retrieve all registration associated to generic interface.
This is the sample code:

```
interface ISample<out T> { }
class Ca : ISample<int> { }
class Cb : ISample<string> { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ISample<int>,Ca>();
        container.RegisterType<ISample<string>, Cb>();

        var classList = container.ResolveAll(typeof(ISample<>));
    }
}
```

in my code this line:

```
var classList = container.ResolveAll(typeof(ISample<>));
```

thows this error:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "ConsoleApplication1Unity.ISample`1[T][]", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - Could not execute the method because either the method itself or the containing type is not fully instantiated.
----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:
  Resolving ConsoleApplication1Unity.ISample`1[T][],(none)
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you post the full message and stack trace please?

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" and other text not directly related to problem (like "new to C#, site,...") to questions. If you feel that thank you are important to your question - please discuss it first on http://meta.stackoverflow.com (but consider reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it first).

Comment: Also please make sure to add exact error message, concrete question (I've remove "help me" style question from the post). Side note: `ISample<>` is frequently called "open generic" and it may help you in searching for answers (also I don't think you can do what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed the task creating following ExtensionMethod

```
public static IEnumerable<object> ResolveAllOpenGeneric(this IUnityContainer container, Type openGenericType)
{
    if (!openGenericType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("argument must be open generic type");

    return container.Registrations.Where(c =>
                                            c.RegisteredType.IsGenericType
                                            && c.RegisteredType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGenericType
                                        )
                                        .Select(r =>
                                                    container.Resolve(r.RegisteredType, r.Name)
                                        );
}

public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAllOpenGeneric<T>(this IUnityContainer container, Type openGenericType)
{
    if (!openGenericType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("argument must be open generic type");

    return container.Registrations.Where(c =>
                                             c.RegisteredType.IsGenericType
                                             && c.RegisteredType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGenericType
                                         )
                                         .Select(r =>
                                                     (T)container.Resolve(r.RegisteredType, r.Name)
                                         );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`ResolveAll` is for finding all named resolutions of a specific type, it does not work with open generics like you are using. To get what you want you would need to do

```
var registrations = container.Registrations
                   .Where(x => x.RegisteredType.IsGenericType && 
                               x.RegisteredType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ISample<>))
                   .ToList();
```

That would give you a list of all registrations. To get a collection of the class objects you just need to call `Resolve` on each registration returned.

```
var classList = new List<object>();
foreach (var registration in registrations)
{
    var classObject = container.Resolve(registration.RegisteredType, registration.Name);
    classList.Add(classObject);
}
```

The only type of `List<T>` that can hold both `ISample<int>` and  `ISample<string>` is `object`. A `List<ISample<object>>` would not work. If you rewrote the interface to be

```
interface ISample { }
interface ISample<out T> : ISample { }
```

It makes the code a lot simpler and you get a better object in the list which would let you access the properties and methods of `ISample` that did not depend on `T`.

```
var registrations = container.Registrations
                   .Where(x => typeof(ISample).IsAssignableFrom(x.RegisteredType));

var classList = new List<ISample>();
foreach (var registration in registrations)
{
    var classObject = container.Resolve(registration.RegisteredType, registration.Name);
    classList.Add((ISample)classObject);
}
```

---

**P.S.** Just to make it clear what the built in `ResolveAll` is doing, it is basically

```
public IEnumerable<object> ResolveAll(Type t, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)
{
    var registrations = this.Registrations.Where(x => x.RegisteredType == t);
    foreach (var registration in registrations)
    {
        if(registration.Name != null)
            yield return this.Resolve(registration.RegisteredType, registration.Name, resolverOverrides)
    }
}
```

Comment: Following you hint I've posted an Extension Method, could you give an advice about?

Answer (score 0):

ISample<> is not a valid type to Unity; you can't register it and you can't use ResolveAll to get all types using it. If you look at what ResolveAll returns, that help show the problem. In this case, it would return an  IEnumerable> which is not valid.

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do so I don't know what to recommend trying.