# Resolve Interface<T> with Unity

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a problem with resolving a Generic Interface mapped to none generic Type.

Registration:

```
UnityContainer.RegisterType<IHandle<SomeEvent>, SomeHandler>();
//UnityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IHandle<SupplierApprovedEvent>), typeof(TestHandler));
```

This is how i try to resolve it without success:

```
 public static void GenericResolver<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
        {
            var handlerType = typeof(IHandle<>).MakeGenericType(args.GetType());
            var firstTry = container.GetServices(handlerType);// Resolve fails
            var secondTry = container.GetServices(typeof(IHandle<T>)); // Resolve fails

            var casted = args as IDomainEvent;
            var handlerType2 = typeof(IHandle<>).MakeGenericType(casted.GetType());
            var thirdTry = container.GetServices(handlerType2);// Resolve fails

            var handlerType3 = typeof(IHandle<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
            var fourthTry = container.GetServices(handlerType3);// Resolve fails
        }
```

My interfaces:

```
public interface IDomainEvent {}

public interface IHandle<T>: IHandle where T : IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle(T args);
}

public interface IHandle
{
    void Handle(IDomainEvent args);
}
```

Interface implementation:

```
public class SomeHandler: IHandle<SomeEvent>
{
    public void Handle(IDomainEvent args)
    {
        Handle(args as SomeEvent);
    }

    public void Handle(SomeEvent args)
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

What do I miss here :!?

**UPDATE:**

1.there are no exceptions.

2.GetService is returning null.

3.This resolve works fine but its not what i want:

```
var itsTypeofSomeHangled =(SomeHandler)injector.GetService(typeof(IHandle<SomeEvent>));
```

4.container in the example is UnityDependencyResolver which inherits IDependencyResolver. This is the reason why i call methods GetServices and GerSevice

**UPDATE2:**
It turns out that the problem is in GetService**s** (ResolveAll). This line works perfectly, but i have more than one implementation of this Gereric Interface.

```
var handlerType = typeof(IHandle<>).MakeGenericType(args.GetType());
var xxxx = (IHandle)container.GetService(handlerType);
```

Comment: Is `GetServices` an extension method that you created yourself? Or do you mean to use `Resolve` instead?

Comment: Why do you call `container.GetServices` instead of `container.Resolve`?

Comment: container is UnityDependencyResolver exposed as IDependencyResolver. Thats why its GetService instead of Resolve

Comment: You say "resolve fails" but do didn't add the exception details (message, type, full stack trace) to your question.

Comment: Why do you use `GetServices` instead of `GetService`?

Comment: `GetServices` would internally call `ResolveAll` on the container which would only use named registrations.

Comment: There is no exception. The get service returns null. Also i tired both GetServices and GetService

Comment: I notice you're registering IHandle<Some...> but trying to resolve just IHandle<>, is this deliberate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what is the problem. Unity resolve all does not work the way i expect in my example. Scott Chamberlain explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148782/unity-resolveall-generics-interface) topic covers it.

Solution:

```
    var handlerType = typeof(IHandle<>).MakeGenericType(args.GetType());
    var handlers = resolver.Container.Registrations
                       .Where(x => x.RegisteredType.IsGenericType && x.RegisteredType == handlerType)
                       .Select(x => (IHandle)resolver.GetService(x.RegisteredType));

    foreach (IHandle item in handlers)
    {
        item.Handle(args);
    }
```

Basically what i did here is to query the container registration to look for my handler type. Than in the .Select i call GetService(Resolve) with the specific registration.RegisteredType parameter and of course cast it. Than in the foreach its obvious...